# Что означает строка Culturelnfo.InvariantCulture в качестве параметра ToUpper()?

Tags: c#

Данная строка выясняет находятся ли символы строки (string) переменной line в верх или нижн регистре, путем сравнения исходной строки с копией с верх регистров. Вроде все понятно, кроме одного момента.

```
Culturelnfo.InvariantCulture
```

что это за аргумент такой в методе ToUpper, в документации не особо понял, что это региональные настройки и тд, в данном случае что данная строка делает, для чего она нужна?

```
if(string.Compare(line.ToUpper (Culturelnfo.InvariantCulture),  line,false) == О);
```

Comment: Например, в турецком алфавите есть буквы I ı (без точки) и  İ i (с точкой). Соответственно, если на компьютере пользователя стоит турецкая культура, то метод `ToUpper()` без параметра превратит i в İ, а не в I, как в большинстве других культур с латинским алфавитом. Короче, культуры очень важны при работе с текстом.